# How to use Google reCAPTCHA in the Ant Design Form component?

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, antd

I'm trying to use [react-recaptcha](https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha) with [antd](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design), the following is my source code:

```
import React from 'react';

import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import Form from 'antd/lib/form';
import Input from 'antd/lib/input';
import Tooltip from 'antd/lib/tooltip';
import Icon from 'antd/lib/icon';
import Cascader from 'antd/lib/cascader';
import Row from 'antd/lib/row';
import Col from 'antd/lib/col';
import Checkbox from 'antd/lib/checkbox';
import Button from 'antd/lib/button';

import Recaptcha from 'react-recaptcha';


const FormItem = Form.Item;

const residences = [{
  value: 'zhejiang',
  label: 'Zhejiang',
  children: [{
    value: 'hangzhou',
    label: 'Hangzhou',
    children: [{
      value: 'xihu',
      label: 'West Lake',
    }],
  }],
}, {
  value: 'jiangsu',
  label: 'Jiangsu',
  children: [{
    value: 'nanjing',
    label: 'Nanjing',
    children: [{
      value: 'zhonghuamen',
      label: 'Zhong Hua Men',
    }],
  }],
}];

class RegisterForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      passwordDirty: false,
    };
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }
  handlePasswordBlur(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ passwordDirty: this.state.passwordDirty || !!value });
  }
  checkPassowrd(rule, value, callback) {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && value !== form.getFieldValue('password')) {
      callback('Two passwords that you enter is inconsistent!');
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }
  checkConfirm(rule, value, callback) {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && this.state.passwordDirty) {
      form.validateFields(['confirm'], { force: true });
    }
    callback();
  }
  myCallback(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  loaded() {
    console.log("loaded");
  }
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: { span: 6 },
      wrapperCol: { span: 14 },
    };
    const tailFormItemLayout = {
      wrapperCol: {
        span: 14,
        offset: 6,
      },
    };
    return (
      <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label={(
            <span>
              Username&nbsp;
              <Tooltip title="What do you want other to call you?">
                <Icon type="question-circle-o" />
              </Tooltip>
            </span>
          )}
          hasFeedback
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Password"
          hasFeedback
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please input your password!',
            }, {
              validator: this.checkConfirm.bind(this),
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" onBlur={this.handlePasswordBlur.bind(this)} />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Confirm Password"
          hasFeedback
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('confirm', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please confirm your password!',
            }, {
              validator: this.checkPassowrd.bind(this),
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="E-mail"
          hasFeedback
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('email', {
            rules: [{
              type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
            }, {
              required: true, message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
            }],
          })(
            <Input />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Habitual Residence"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('residence', {
            initialValue: ['zhejiang', 'hangzhou', 'xihu'],
            rules: [{ type: 'array', required: true, message: 'Please select your habitual residence!' }],
          })(
            <Cascader options={residences} />
          )}
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem {...tailFormItemLayout} style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('agreement', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please check the agreement!' }],
          })(
            <Checkbox>I had read the <a>agreement</a></Checkbox>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <Recaptcha
          sitekey='mykeyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmykey'
          onloadCallback={this.loaded.bind(this)}
          verifyCallback={this.myCallback.bind(this)}
        />
        <FormItem {...tailFormItemLayout}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" size="large">Register</Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form.create()(RegisterForm);
```

But in the web page, the reCAPTCHA can not even show up. I think the `Form` component is a little magic and I probably did some thing not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Especially two things may need attention:

1. Declare the `const RecaptchaItem = React.createClass({..})` globally, do not make it a local variable  in `render()`
2. Must provide `onloadCallback` and `verifyCallback` both, if `onloadCallback` is missing, the reCAPTCHA will not trigger calling `verifyCallback` and the Form can not get the value. This is probably a bug of react-recaptcha

Here is the correct code:

```
const { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } = antd;
const FormItem = Form.Item;

const RecaptchaItem = React.createClass({
  verifyCallback(result) {
    console.log('verifyCallback', result);
    this.props.onChange(result); // notify the form after verified
  },
  render() {
    return (<ReactRecaptcha
      render="explicit"
      sitekey="6LdSLAwUAAAAAFBwEUIlvzTxJE8zpRlh9r87eCL5"
      onloadCallback={() => {}}       
      verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback}
    />);
  }
});

const NormalLoginForm = Form.create()(React.createClass({
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  },
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="user" />} placeholder="Username" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
          })(
            <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="lock" />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('captcha', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input the captcha you got!' }],
          })(<RecaptchaItem />)}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
            initialValue: true,
          })(
            <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
          )}
          <a className="login-form-forgot">Forgot password</a>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
            Log in
          </Button>
          Or <a>register now!</a>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  },
}));

ReactDOM.render(<NormalLoginForm />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

See [the live demo here](http://codepen.io/RaoHai/pen/dOOgPj)

The most valuable information is already in this answer, in case someone who is interested, however, here is the original discussion link on Github issue: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/3878